# Extra whitespace is being added at the top of the NavigationBar

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, whitespace, navigationbar

I am relatively new to using SwiftUI and have run into a problem that I cannot find any solution to online, I will try and explain it as well as possible.

I am building an app that involves a side-menu pullout that contains NavigationLinks to various other pages. There is a struct named SideMenu that contains all of the NavigationLinks and its own NavigationView because that is called once in the first page (or else the NavigationBars stack on top of each other as you move further into the app). A basic representation of the code:

```
struct MenuContent: View {    
    var body: some View {
        // the various buttons and their NavigationLinks
    }
}
```

When running this side-menu on the Canvas preview inside of XCode the screen is displayed like this:
[image]

This is the view that I would like in the completed app. But when I run the code in the simulator (which opens the external XCode application) this is the view that occurs:

[image]

As one can see there is white space added at the top of the NavigationBar which does not appear on the Preview Canvas representation. Any reason as to why this is occurring would be very much appreciated.

Comment: You have the View wrapped in two NavigationViews

Comment: Would you show your code? Especially everything where NavigationView is used/configured.

Answer (score 0):

As answered in the comments the reason for this error was the existence of two NavigationViews.

Specifically, there was a first view that had its NavigationBar hidden which then linked to a second view which then branched into the main part of the app. This second view contained a non-hidden NavigationBar. When the simulator was ran it was stacking the blank hidden NavigationBar at the top of the second view's non-hidden NavigationBar.